# CountIF returns 0 with array and criteria in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a large array of data, consisting of start and end date/time for license use. I'm trying to count how many users are active at the same time.

I'm using the below formula, but I get a return value of 0 some places, which basically shouldn't be possible.

```
=CountIFs(E$2:E$5616;"<="&E1108;F$2:F$5616;">"&E1108)
```

Is the approach wrong or is there a better one?

Edit: Added extra screendump showing the 6 places I have a 0 returned. Have run a clean and trim on the data as well, with no changes to the output.

Edit2: Added npciture showing the difference between my two CountIf and Sumproduct outputs. Is there something I'm missing here, the data should be exactly the same so the output should be 1 and 2 for everything?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess the Danish formula actually translates to `COUNTIFS` and your parameter delimiter is the semi-colon (locale settings). However are you sure all data is actual numeric data? No leading/trailing spaces or illegal characters? You can try implement `CLEAN` and `TRIM`. Note, there should be no reason to enter as array.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with rounding. Seems to me your formula should return a zero for row `1107` where `start=end` but I cannot reproduce your error here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, there is only a fraction of data for us to see here. And rounding issues seems unlikely on row 1108. I also can't repro the issue =(

Comment: @JvdV clearly, there's something we're missing. A rounding issue might occur if the start / end times are produced by a formula

Comment: *which basically shouldn't be possible* Are you 100% absolutely sure it's not possible? Because it looks like the formula works in rest of cells. Try filtering manually applying those conditions, and count how mnay visible rows you got.

Comment: I think it's a bug in COUNTIFS and how it deals with numbers with a lot of significant figures. I'd suggest you use SUMPRODUCT instead.

Comment: The data represents Date and Time, so there is a lot of trailing decimal digits not shown. Tried @JvdV suggestion with Clean and Trim with no changes. Did a manual check on row 2529 with an And formula with the same <= and > and it returns true.

Comment: @Rory Not that familiar with Sumproduct, would this be the correct syntax? `=SUMPRODUKT(--(E$2:E$5616<=E2);--(F$2:F$5616>E2))`

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: @Rory Just did a control between two different rows of CountIF and Sumproduct getting different results. Just checked that B=E and C=F is true. Why is there a different output from the CountIF, any suggestions? Just curious now as I would like to verify that my Sumproduct is showing the correct data, what with CountIF not working for me?

Comment: There seems to be an occasional issue with COUNTIF(S) when a high level of precision is stored in the cell value. I assume it has to do with the function's attempts to coerce anything that looks like a number to an actual number. SUMPRODUCT doesn't attempt any coercion.

Comment: @Rory feel free to leave an answer, and I'll mark it as solved using Sumproduct.

Comment: Did you try using the "evaluate formula" Excel feature? This allows you to evaluate a function step by step which gives you the possibility to see which step goes wrong.

Comment: @Dominique Tried evaluting, but didn't really give any useable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `COUNTIFS`, since it isn't susceptible to the same number coercion issues:

```
=SUMPRODUKT(--(E$2:E$5616<=E2);--(F$2:F$5616>E2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=COUNTIFS(E$2:E$5616,  "<=" & E1108, F$2:F$5616, ">" & E1108)`

Replace `,` with `;`

Comment: There might be something different going on because the formula in the screenshot is actually translated as `COUNTIFS` (just translated that) and the locale parameter delimiter is the semi-colon. So this is basically a translation of the exact same formula OP used

Comment: My locale makes it so I have to use the `;` and not a `,`. Else it will not run at all.